# ElasticSearch Spark CPU Utilization shoots to 300%

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I have a Spark Cluster with 12 cores and 10GB RAM.
Effectively two machines running in clustered mode.
On these same two machines I have also set up a ElasticSearch cluster.

I am writing around 150 000 records every sec... in batches of 5000 
However, both the Java Processes of Elasticsearch and Spark use around 300% CPU when the Batch insert mode starts :(

Can someone shed some light as to what is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by lakh?

Comment: @eliasah, WoodChopper has correctly indicated 1.5 lakh = 150,000

Comment: It is telling you to increase your batch size :)

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a problem, just a maxing out of 3 of your 12 CPUs.